Steiner Ellipse and Inscribed Circle
The inscribed Steiner Ellipse of an n-simplex $\Sigma$ is the unique ellipse tangent at the faces of $\Sigma$ and having centre the centroid of $\Sigma$.
Suppose i have two simplices $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$. Let $S_1,S_2$ be the respective inscribed spheres and $E(\Sigma_1),E(\Sigma_2)$ be the respective inscribed Steiner ellipses. Moreover it is known that the Steiner ellipses have orthogonal half axes (of possibly different lengths). Given $S_1\subset S_2$, is it possible to claim $E_1\subset E_2$ (after transforming the ambient space so that the centres and axes of the ellipses align).
It seems unlikely, but i could not construct an example.

Here's a counterexample in the plane:

One incircle contains the other, but neither inellipse contains its counterpart.
Here's a symmetric one, with isosceles triangles:

And here's one where the major axes align:


To make the figure in GeoGebra, I started with the overlapping ellipses centered at the origin (with axes of symmetry aligned with the coordinate axes).
I chose a point on one ellipse and dilated that in the origin, with scale factor $-2$ (because the centroid divides a triangle's median in the ratio $1:2$), to get the opposite vertex of the corresponding triangle. The tangent line at the chosen point, and the tangent lines through the dilated point, determined the complete triangle. Choosing a point on the other ellipse likewise determined the other triangle.
From there, I constructed the incircles, and moved the chosen points around the ellipses until one incircle fell completely inside the other.
